# How can I remove all restrictions of access to my repositories in VisualSVN Server so that nothing is impeding me from accessing/writing files?

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn-server

I'm running into a really obnoxious error: "svn: E175013: Access to [repo path] forbidden" while trying to branch from a tag. My user had "Read/Write" permissions inherited from parent, but I also tried setting my user permissions explicitly to Read/Write at the path location. I tried this with other folders above and below too, just for fun. But none of these settings work. So I'm looking for simple ways to (at least temporarily) completely turn off any sort of access restrictions as a sanity check. What other files/settings should I know about that are relevant? In the past I've only ever had to right-click on a location, go to Properties, and grant "Read/Write" access when I've needed that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and should not disable authorization checks in VisualSVN Server. The error `svn: E175013: Access to [repo path] forbidden` means that something is wrong with your account's permissions and you need to double-check them.

Hope you will find one of these hints helpful:

1. Examine the permissions again. I think that there is a 'ReadOnly' or 'NoAccess' access rule on /branches/ or /branches/yournewbranchname and it applies to your user account either directly or through group membership. Make sure that you read the article [KB33: Understanding VisualSVN Server authorization](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/).
2. Examine the [log **VisualSVN Server**](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/#logs). You will see an event relevant to these Access Forbidden errors. These events have path which you are not authorized to access.
3. Use the [`Get-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule) PowerShell cmdlet to view the list of all access rules. Unlike the graphical admin console, the cmdlet lists access rules for paths that do not exist in HEAD (youngest) revision. The admin console lets you view and manage only the access rules for directories and files that are present in the HEAD revision. If there is an access rule for a non-existent path, you can only see it using PowerShell.